# Is there an address gazetteer for QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have a SQL database that has our local address database on it - it has no geometry within it, just a list of addresses and X and Y co-ordinates. I want to use this data to enable people to search for an address within QGIS and find it on the map?

Any help would be greatly appreciated... otherwise it's a crash-course in python for me!

Comment: Can anyone shed any light on configuring the Astun Gazetteer plugin to use my own gazetteer (as a web service)?

Comment: please ask your question as a separate question, and reference this question for details.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Astun Technology have done some work on one, with example connections to Yahoo  and their own gazetteer: https://github.com/AstunTechnology/QGIS-Gazetteer-Plugin.  I've had a quick look, as I was hoping to integrate to our own gazetteer, but got diverted on to another project so can't comment on how to hook it up, my alternative was to look at building a webservice on the gazetteer and using that from Python, but not had chance to start scoping it out as yet.

Comment: I've had a look at that, but it seems mainly focused on web based searches, not on using a connection to a local database... it would probably work if, as you mention, building a web service from your gazetteer and then configuring the Astun tool to run your search..

Answer (score 1):

QGIS [Discovery](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/Discovery/) Plugin from Lutra Consulting can be used. The recent [blog post](http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2016/04/25/Setting-up-Discovery-plugin/) explains how to set it up